# How to Send/Receive ISO 8583 messages with WSo2 ESB ?

Tags: wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 and would like to know how to use this technology to deal with ISO-8583 messages with TCP/IP Transport. I am glad if anyone could assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB supports ISO8583 through an inbound endpoint and a connector. You can find the artifacts at [WSO2 Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/e4cf3fd5-445f-4317-beb6-09998906fb0d).
The ISO8583 inbound endpoint allows you to consume the ISO8583 standard messages and connector allows you to access the ISO8583 Standard messages through WSO2 ESB.